# Starting two rigid body animations at different points in time

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rigid-body-simulation

I am animating a rigid body in cycles but I am experiencing problems when it comes to other rigid bodies. As you can see I would to PEN (White one) to drop after the three rings but both of them seem to occur at the same time. Please Help.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I think it would be better to split your question to two. One for the keyframing and another for the rolling effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the pen then go to the frame in which you don't want the pen to fall (presumably frame 1) and uncheck the `Dynamic` tick in the rigid body menu. Then mouse over the tick and press `I`.

[image]

This adds a key-frame. Then go to the frame where you *want* it to fall, and check the `Dynamic` box (so it's on) and press `I` to add another key-frame. Then the object will have dynamic rigid collision when the key-frame is hit.

[image]

Comment: Glad to help :)